# Alignment issue in ie9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

This is the link of [my website](http://shopping.na1.netsuite.com/s.nl/c.3563610/sc.8/category.3/.f)  which is looking good in firefox.but in IE items are not in the same line how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is in the HTML, not in the css, you have two extra closing divs at the bottom for each 'item_container span3'

```
    <form method='post' name='form124' id='form124' action='/app/site/backend/additemtocart.nl?c=3563610&amp;n=1' onsubmit="return checkmandatory124();">


    <div class="item_container span3">
    <a href="/s.nl/c.3563610/it.A/id.124/.f" class='lnk13b-blackOff'; onMouseover="this.className='lnk13b-blackOff'; return true;" onMouseout="this.className='lnk13b-blackOff'; return true;">iPhone 5</a>
    <div class="heading_price">
    <span class="price">Price: 
    <span id=itemprice124>?.?.?2?444?00 &#150; 3,649.00 SAR</span>   
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="itemlist-img">
    <a href="/s.nl/c.3563610/it.A/id.124/.f">
    <a href='/s.nl/c.3563610/it.A/id.124/.f'>
    <img src='/core/media/media.nl?id=959&amp;c=3563610&amp;h=b417dd449e62d8ecd270&amp;resizeid=-1&amp;resizeh=214&amp;resizew=160' border='0' alt='Item Images13.jpg' title='Item Images13.jpg'></a></a>
    </div><div><p class="item_desc">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem</p></div>
    <div class="cart_details"><a href="/s.nl/c.3563610/it.A/id.124/.f" class="view_item" onMouseover="this.className='view_item'; return true;" onMouseout="this.className='view_item'; return true;"> VIEW DETAILS</a>
    <span class="cart_btn"><a href="#inline_content"  class='inline'>ADD TO CART</a></span>
    </div></div>

<--- this --->
    **</div></div>**
<------------>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't fixed alignment issue still single item is displaying in IE9.